# Derivative in the distributional sense

Tags: distribution-theory

Let $f\in L_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$, we define the function $g(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$. The quesion is to show that the derivative of $g$ is $f$ in the in the distributional sense.

I know the locally integrable function define distributions, but how is $g$ a distribution??

Comment: $g$ being the integral of an $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ function is actually continuous. So, $g$ is also in $L^1_{\text{loc}}$.

Answer (score 0):

1. **$g$ is continuous:**

To show that, let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N^*}}$ a sequence convergent to $x_0$. We show that $(g(x_n))_n$ converges to $g(x_0)$
$$g(x_n)=\int_0^{x_n}f(t)dt=\int_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{1}_{[0;x_n]}(t)f(t)dt$$
the sequence of functions $(1_{[0;x_n]}f)_n$ converges pointwise to $1_{[0;x_0]}f$, and we know that every convegent sequence is bounded, hence, there exist an $M>0$ such that $[0;x_n]\subset[-M;M]$, which yields the domination $$|{1}_{[0;x_n]}(t)f(t)|\leq {1}_{[-M;M]}(t)|f(t)|$$ Notice that the function on the right is integrable. So by the dominated convergence theorem we get the desired result.

**2. $g'=f$ in the in the distributional sense.**

Let $\varphi \in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ a test function and let $A>0$ such that $supp (\varphi) \subset[-A, A]$. By Fubini, we get:
$$
\begin{aligned}
<g^{\prime}, \varphi>&=-<g, \varphi^{\prime}>=-\int_{-A}^{A}\left(\int_{0}^{x} f(t) \mathrm{d} t\right) \varphi^{\prime}(x) \mathrm{d} x \\
&=-\int_{0}^{A} \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \varphi^{\prime}(x) \mathrm{d} t \mathrm{~d} x+\int_{-A}^{0} \int_{x}^{0} f(t) \varphi^{\prime}(x) \mathrm{d} t \mathrm{~d} x \\
&=-\int_{0}^{A} g(t)\left(\int_{t}^{A} \varphi^{\prime}(x) \mathrm{d} x\right) \mathrm{d} t+\int_{-A}^{0} f(t)\left(\int_{-A}^{t} \varphi^{\prime}(x) \mathrm{d} x\right) \mathrm{d} t \\
&=\int_{0}^{A} f(t) \varphi(t) \mathrm{d} t+\int_{-A}^{0} f(t) \varphi(t) \mathrm{d} t=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t) \varphi(t) \mathrm{d} t=<f, \varphi>
\end{aligned}
$$
Which shows that  $g^{\prime}=f$ in the distributional sense.